# How to add a pickerView in tableViewCell in swift?

Tags: swift

I would like to add a pickerView in tableView cell when I tap it.

just like this pic
[image]

but instead of a datePicker, i want to add a pickerView to choose gender or favorite food etc..

but I found few example and solution on google, is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable to check for `indexPaths` that need to have a `UIPickerView`:

```
var indexesNeedPicker: [NSIndexPath]?
```

Then append those `indexPaths` in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.
Also remove them if they have already been added

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexesNeedPicker != nil {
        if indexesNeedPicker!.contains(indexPath) == true {
            indexesNeedPicker!.removeAtIndex((indexesNeedPicker!.indexOf(indexPath))!)
            return
        }
    }
    indexesNeedPicker?.append(indexPath)
    self.table.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    self.table.reloadData()
}
```

Then edit your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    if indexesNeedPicker?.contains(indexPath) == true {
        let pickerView = UIPickerView(frame: cell.frame)
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        cell.addSubview(pickerView)
    }
    return cell
}
```

Add the delegates to your ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
```

And lastly, add and customize the methods:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    <#code#>
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    <#code#>
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    <#code#>
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    <#code#>
}
```